# Как вычесть содержимое одной таблицы из второй?

Tags: dbf

Итак,имеется две таблицы, как вычесть содержимое одной из второй? Одинаковые поля - фамилии и имена.

Comment: select field from table1 minus select field from table 2

Comment: Укажите средства, которыми вы располагаете, например sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, так: 
1. Получить нужные поля из первой таблицы

> ("SELECT fio,name FROM firsttable")

2. Записать эти значения в переменные `$fio` и `$name`
3. Сформировать запрос во вторую таблицу так:

> ("DELETE "то что хотим удалить" FROM secondtable WHERE fio='$fio' AND
>   name=$name");

Comment: Спасибо, сработало))